# Populating dropdown list with json

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to populate dropdown list with json data. In this code I have received data with ajax. It is also shown in the alert in json format but the drop down list is not populated. I am stuck. Please help..

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://10.0.2.2/Quizapp/getsubcategory.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert(data);
                    $.getJSON('data', function(data) {
                        employees = data.items1;
                        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
                            $("#subcategory").append("<option value='"+employee.scid+"'>"+employee.Name+"</option>");
                            //alert("1.."+employee.scid);
                        });
                    });
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Comment: is your alert functioning properly

Comment: yes it is. Json data is also showing in alert.{"items1":[{"scid":"1","Name":"Oops","cid":"1"}]}.. this is the json data showing in alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You want `$.parseJSON`, not `$.getJSON`.
- You should not have "data" in quotes.

Your final result should look something like this:

```
var items = $.parseJSON(data).items1;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   $("#subcategory").append("<option value='"+items[i].scid+"'>"+items[i].Name+"</option>");
}
```

Also, you should probably not build HTML strings like that because you then have to worry about quoting. Instead, do this:

```
$("#subcategory").append($("<option/>").attr("value", items[i].scid).html(items[i].name));
```

Comment: Actually the data is in json format and i dont know how to populate it in drop down list.

Comment: Oh, derp. You need $.parseJSON, not $.getJSON. I amended my answer.

Comment: How to use $.parseJSON in my code. Can you please help.

Comment: See my amended answer above. I tried to sort it all out for you. You've gotten into the weeds a bit.